# Memcpy and two-dimensial arrays

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, memcpy, submatrix

What I am trying to do is to copy a part of matrix to an other in order to create a submatrix. However, while the following part of code looks quiet logical to me, it results in absolutely nothing being copied into a destination.

```
void Copy(double **mt, int sx, int ex, int sy, int ey, double **res)
{
int i;
int t = sizeof(double)*(ey-sy+1);
for(i = 0; i < ex-sx+1; i++)
    memcpy(&mt[i][0],&res[sx+i][sy], t);
return;
}
```

Comment: The no 2D array, actually not even a 1D array or array of pointers.

Comment: `&mt[i][0]` and `&res[sx+i][sy]` should lead to compile error since `mt[i]` and `res[sx+i]` are neither array nor pointer.

Comment: Pardon me, that was my typo. It is actually supposed to be a two-dimensial array.

Comment: Your code [copied something](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vt761OFZc8d8PsoZ). Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).